# Calculating azimuth values along line for its segments using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, line, azimuth, segment

[image]

How can I calculate the azimuths along a line on its segments ?

Is there a function in PostGIS for this?

I want to calculate the min, max, sum and avg value of the azimuths for each segment.

Comment: The pictures you present have two different approaches, you have already been given an answer for the picture on the right, and for the picture on the left... you had to divide your question into two questions...

Comment: The answer to the picture on the left *should* be `ST_Azimuth(SOURCE, TARGET)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `ST_Azimuth` sequentially on all possible vertex pairs of a line; `ST_DumpPoints` the vertices first, then run `ST_Azimuth` with the current and the `LEAD` vertex:

```
SELECT  <id>,
        SUM(azm), AVG(azm), MIN(azm), MAX(azm)
FROM    (
  SELECT <id>,
         DEGREES(ST_Azimuth((dmp).geom, LEAD((dmp).geom) OVER(PARTITION BY <id> ORDER BY (dmp).path))) AS azm
  FROM   <your_table>,
         LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(geom) AS dmp
) q
GROUP BY
        <id>
;
```

where `<id>` is your unique line ID column.

Comment: what does the )q towards the end of your answer mean? I want the azimuth of each line segment in a road network. 
I tried the below but it seems wrong. I exploded the lines into individual segments. 
```CREATE VIEW attempt1 AS
  SELECT line_id, gid, road_exp.geom,
         DEGREES(ST_Azimuth((dmp).geom, LEAD((dmp).geom) OVER(PARTITION BY gid ORDER BY (dmp).path))) AS az
  FROM   road_exp,
         LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(geom) AS dmp
; ```
any tips?