# Calculating azimuth values relatively along line for its segments using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, azimuth

I'm trying to make this calculation in SQL with PostGIS:

```
azimuth_1 + (Sum rel_azimuth_2 to rel_azimuth_7)
```

rel_azimuth_x is always the angle beetween the actual subsegment_x and one subsegment_x-1 before.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*As clarification of, and in addition to, [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/340004/93656) to [your earlier question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340000/calculating-azimuth-values-along-line-for-its-segments-using-postgis):*

If you want to add up the relative angles between two segments and the `SOURCE` (that is what your image suggests), you can do so by using [`ST_Angle`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_Angle.html) (*note that there is a 3 point function signature not explicitly explained in the docs!*) and a similar construct to my other answer (for completeness sake I will simply add up to that query):

```
SELECT  id,
        -- aggregates for absolute azimuths
        SUM(seg_azm) AS sum_azm,  -- SUM(seg_azm)::NUMERIC % 360.0 AS sum_azm
        AVG(seg_azm) AS avg_azm,
        MIN(seg_azm) AS min_azm,
        MAX(seg_azm) AS max_azm,
        -- aggregates for relative angles
        SUM(seg_ang) AS sum_ang,  -- SUM(seg_ang)::NUMERIC % 360.0 AS sum_ang
        AVG(seg_ang) AS avg_ang,
        MIN(seg_azm) AS min_ang,
        MAX(seg_azm) AS max_ang,
        -- azimuth between SOURCE & TARGET as reference
        (SELECT DEGREES(ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint(geom), ST_EndPoint(geom))) FROM <your_table> WHERE id = q.id) AS st_azm
FROM    (
  SELECT a.id,
         -- absolute azimuths of two-pair segments
         DEGREES(ST_Azimuth((dmp).geom, LEAD((dmp).geom) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path))) AS seg_azm,
         -- relative angles between vertex - source - next vertex
         DEGREES(ST_Angle((dmp).geom, ST_StartPoint(a.geom), LEAD((dmp).geom) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path))) AS seg_ang
  FROM   <your_table> AS a,
         LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(a.geom) AS dmp
) q
GROUP BY
        id
;
```

**Notes:**

- the plain `SUM` of any of those angles are useless; I added the modulo calculation as comments to get the normalized azimuth and angle
- I added the azimuth between the `SOURCE` and `TARGET` in the outer `SELECT` as reference; **if you add up the initial (first segment) azimuth to the normalized angle you will get this value!**

Comment: where is the "segs" table ?  or what means the "segs" Relation »segs« doesn't exist
  Position: 610 --> yoe mean <your table>

Comment: @Tibor ah, sorry, that's a leftover from my test; replace that with the same value (e.g. table name) you put as `<your_table>`. I corrected that in the answer.

Comment: should i also add a modolo calculation for the segments from the line in the angle calculation ?

Comment: well, those angles will be treated as plain numbers when summed up, so you'll end up with a value far greater than 360. the modulo will give you the normalized angle, zero based (so, if the sum is 1100, you'll get 20; '*made a full turn 3 times, plus 20 degrees*'). or do you mean adding another modulo operation?? no.

Comment: i take a mistake - i need the angels not from the start points source  to the endpoints of each segments rather between each segment pairs 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, ...

Comment: i add a picture

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVJDP.jpg

Answer (score 0):

[image: directed angle - Problems with group by....]

i changed the code but i have a problem, if i build a group over the directedid i get a much more value for the directed angle.

---

If the directid is inside the select for directed angle i get this angles...

```
directedid  |path|angle_directed|angle_clockwise |
------------|----|--------------|----------------|
1000344165_2|{1} |9.845519416014|189.845519416014|
1000344165_2|{2} |              |                |
1000344165_2|{3} |              |                |
```

is the where outside or i build the group by directed id i get

```
directedid  |sum               |
------------|------------------|
1000344165_2|350.15448058398595|
```

---

here is the code...

`select 
    line.directedid
    , sum(line.angle_directed)
    , min(line.angle_directed)
    , max(line.angle_directed) 
from (
SELECT 
    a.directedid
    , dmp.path
    ,   case 
            when DEGREES(ST_Angle( st_transform((dmp).geom,31468), LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468)) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path) , LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468),2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path)))::numeric % 360 <= 180 then
                abs(180 - DEGREES(ST_Angle( st_transform((dmp).geom,31468), LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468)) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path) , LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468),2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path)))::numeric % 360)
            when DEGREES(ST_Angle( st_transform((dmp).geom,31468), LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468)) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path) , LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468),2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path)))::numeric % 360 is null then
                0
            else 
                DEGREES(ST_Angle( st_transform((dmp).geom,31468), LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468)) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path) , LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468),2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path)))::numeric % 360 - 180
            end angle_directed
    , DEGREES(ST_Angle( st_transform((dmp).geom,31468), LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468)) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path) , LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468),2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path)))::numeric % 360 angle_clockwise
    --, st_transform((dmp).geom,31468)
    --, LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468)) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path)
    --, LEAD(st_transform((dmp).geom,31468),2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (dmp).path)
FROM  edge_table AS a, 
Lateral ST_DumpPoints(st_transform(a.geom,31468)) AS dmp - -where directedid = '1_1' --inside 
) as line 
-- where directedid = '1_1' -- outside
group by directedid`